# Migrating existing Login flow using Instagram Legacy API to the new Instagram Basic graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, instagram-api

Our application (kind-of got legacy) has been using IG API to authorize users (by using the **uid** attribute returned from IG's callback API response) and we have left email as an optional param (safe to assume that there are many users in the application database without email IDs persisted)

With new **Instagram Basic Display API** (*advised*), it's mentioned to use **Facebook Login** for authentication purpose. But I am facing a major problem of *identifying existing users* now (since the uid will be **different**).

Also I have a doubt on what will have happen for users having instagram account without linking their Facebook account to it?

I could not find a proper explanation or a documentation for seamless migration for my situation.

Please help with sharing the right resource or guidance to achieve the same.

Comment: I don’t think there is any “documentation for seamless migration”. Check if any of the fields you can request from the `IG User` object help, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/user#fields They don’t specifically say _what_ the `id` field will be here, it might be the IG user id? If not, maybe you can use the username – if you have the recorded in your existing data.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the suggestions, may be I will try to fetch the id and see if it has the :uid.
But I have to do this while logging users in, which is discouraged by FB team now and I think it's tough to get the App Reviewed if I follow that path.